# Substitute with multiple old_text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

`A1` may contains one of this two values:

1. Person 2
2. Numbers 2

I need returns in `A2`:

1. 2
2. 2

I have tried `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(J23,"Persons",""))`

How can assign multiple values in `old_text` field?

Comment: It seems that you want to return second part of the string after space. Is it correct understanding?

Comment: Sometimes there is no spaces.

Comment: I want return numeric part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nest SUBSTITUTE function if you know all possible substitutes and they are not too many like below:

`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Person",""),"Numbers",""))`

Or you can choose approach like below which is based on your posted sample which assumes numeric part is always on the right hand side.

`=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789",1)),LEN(A1))`

Hope this helps!